# How to verify column count using protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I need to verify the column count of a table based off of the security role of the logged in user. How can I verify that in some instances 5 columns are displayed but in other instances 4 or 3?

The columns all use a unique `"ng-class="{ 'sortable': sortable }"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, [`.count()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.count) should do the job:

```
var columns = $$(".sortable");
expect(columns.count()).toEqual(5);
```

If some of the columns are visible or not, you can *filter the visible columns only*:

```
var columns = $$(".sortable").filter(function (column) {
    return column.isDisplayed().then(function (isDisplayed) {
        return isDisplayed;
    });
}); 
expect(columns.count()).toEqual(5);
```